# In my laravel 8, i need to show all the licenses related to a single beat ($id) in the beatreferencing license table with beat_id in the show.blade

Tags: laravel

//Genre Model//
class Genre extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $table = 'genres';
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'slug', 'status', 'popular',
];

/**
 * Get all of the licenses for the user.
 */

public function beat()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Beat::class);
}

public function license()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(license::class, Beat::class);
}
```

}

//Beat Model//
class Beat extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $table = 'beats';
protected $fillable = [
    'genre_id',
    'name',
    'slug',
    'image',
    'status',
    'new',
    'trending',
    'meta_title',
    'meta_keywords',
];

public function license()
{
    return $this->hasMany(License::class,'beat_id', 'id');
}

public function genre()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Genre::class, 'genre_id', 'id');
}
```

}

//License//
{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $table = 'licenses';

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

protected $fillable = [
    'beat_id',
    'license_name',
    'beat_name',
    'genre',
    'bpm',
    'key',
    'tag_1',
    'tag_2',
    'time',
    'price',
    'status',
    'popular',
    'wav',
    'trackout',
    'unlimited',
    'exclusive',
    'image',
    'audio',
];

public function beat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Beat::class, 'id');
}
```

}

//LicenseController//

```
public function show($id)
{
    
    $license = License::find($id);

    return view('admin.license.show')->with('license', $license,);
}
```

// Show.blade.php//

```
  @extends('layouts.admin')

 @section('content')
 <div class="container">
    @foreach($licenses->chunk(4) as $license)
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach($licenses as $license)
            <div class="">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/uploads/licenses/img/'.$license->image) }}"  
                alt="image here">
                <p>{{ $license->id }}</p>
                <p>{{ $license->beat_id }}</p>
                <p>{{ $license->beat_name }}</p>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>`enter code here`
    @endforeach
 </div>
 @endsection
```

Anytime i try to use  @foreach to call

{{ $license->beat->id }}

, it give me errors like this Error:

Method name must be a string
http://127.0.0.1:8000/licenses/1

Comment: Your query will return a single Lincense object. I guess what you want is License::where('beat_id', $id)->get();

Comment: ->with('license', $license,) this syntax is legal as of php 7.3 when trailing commas in function calls was added.

Comment: are you suggesting this for the show.blade? and what is the correct syntax ? @porloscerros

Comment: I need to select all the beat_id in license table that is related to a beat in beat table @porloscerros

Comment: oh.... sorry i have remove the comma @mrhn

Comment: @porloscerros - it's the value of the beat on the license table which is the beat_id

Comment: @porloscerros-  when i use your solution licence controller i got an error "ErrorException
Undefined variable: id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the licenses related to a single beat, if you have the beat id in the `$id` variable, you can do the query like this:

```
License::where('beat_id', $id)->get();
```

So, your controller function could look like this:

//LicenseController//

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $licenses = License::where('beat_id', $id)->get();

    return view('admin.license.show')->with('licenses', $licenses);
}
```

Then in the view you can loop over the licences collection to show each one:

// Show.blade.php//

```php
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    @foreach($licenses as $license)
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="">
                <img src="{{ asset('assets/uploads/licenses/img/'.$license->image) }}" alt="image here">
                <p>License Id: {{ $license->id }}</p>
                <p>License Name: {{ $license->license_name }}</p>
                <p>License Beat Id: {{ $license->beat_id }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: trying to diplay show.blade in another controller called FrontController using a bootstrap modal. but showing error "Undefined variable: item (View:" please help on what to do

Comment: Please help. have a FrontendController and others like BeatController, LicenseController and GenreController, now i ran into a problem when i want to view the show.blade.php in licenseController to my FrontendController using a bootstrap modal

Comment: @pajay open a new question forma that

Comment: ok i will do that

Answer (score 1):

Your organization is a bit strange, as I'd expect to see this method called something more like `BeatController::showLicenses()`. But setting that aside, you should be using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) to automate a lot of this stuff. This is what your controller method should look like:

```php
public function show(Beat $beat)
{
    return view('admin.license.show')->with('licenses', $beat->licenses);
}
```

If you define your route with a parameter called `beat` instead of `id`, something like this:

```php
Route::get('/admin/license/{beat}', [LicenseController::class, 'show']);
```

The type hint in the method signature will signal the routing engine to automatically do the database lookup for you. As a bonus, it also handles 404 errors in case in invalid ID is passed.

Comment: ok, i will look into it, thanks.

Comment: Please help. have a FrontendController and others like BeatController, LicenseController and GenreController, now i ran into a problem when i want to view the show.blade.php in licenseController to my FrontendController using a bootstrap modal @ miken32