# How to get a single row by id in my laravel 8 project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i'm new to laravel and trying to show a single row using its (id) in my view.blade.php, right now it works, but when i select another license_id it only shows' the contents of the first row (id) since they have same foriegn key, and the funny thing is that the route shows that am in the license_id i selected.

```
public function viewlicense($id)
{
    if(Beat::where('id', $id)->exists())
    {
        if(License::where('beat_id', $id)->exists())
        {
            $licenses = License::where('beat_id', $id)->first();
            return view('frontend.licenses.view', compact('licenses'));
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/')->with('Status', "The link was broken");
        }
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/')->with('Status', "No such beat found");
    }
}




Route::get('/', [FrontendController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('beat', [FrontendController::class, 'beat']);
Route::get('view-beat/{id}', [FrontendController::class, 'viewbeat']);
Route::get('view-beat/{beat_slug}/{license_slug}', [FrontendController::class, 'viewlicense']);
```

Edited Code

```
public function beat()
{
    $beats = Beat::all();
    return view('frontend.beat', compact('beats'));
}

public function viewbeat($slug)
{
    if(Beat::where('slug', $slug)->exists())
    {
        $beat = Beat::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $licenses = License::where('beat_id', $beat->id)->get();
        return view('frontend.licenses.index', compact('beat', 'licenses'));
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/')->with('Status', "id doesnot exists");
    }
}

public function viewlicense($beat_slug, $license_slug)
{
    if(Beat::where('slug', $beat_slug)->exists())
    {
        if(License::where('slug', $license_slug)->exists())
        {
            $licenses = License::where('slug', $license_slug)->first();
            return view('frontend.licenses.view', compact('licenses'));
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/')->with('Status', "The link was broken");
        }
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/')->with('Status', "No such beat found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what you need?

Comment: But there is multiple licenses, so your frontend probably has to show multiple?

Comment: Question 1: why are you selecting the licenses in a new query, and not a relationship? Question 2 : you use `first()` so...  how do you expect it to return another license then the first one?

Comment: Your route also has 2 parameters, your action function only one.. . There's a lot of things wrong in your code. Another strange thing: your parameter is called {beat_slug} and your function has a parameter '$id'... very confusing

Comment: i want to select a a single row which will then have a checkout page or goes to cart - @silentwasd

Comment: @Gert B - yes, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Start by choosing if you want to use slugs or ID's. Since it is in the frontend, slugs would be better. If your route has 2 parameters, your action should have the same two parameters. After that, you can simply get the license with one simple query. for example : `License::where('slug', $license_slug)->first()`

Comment: @GertB. I initially use the slug all through but still having the same problem, then i swich to the id and still having same outcome, but the id made me to discover that my route actually point to the id i required

Comment: Using ID or slug is a choice. Frontend I would use slugs for SEO. It does not change how it works, it only changes your where statement.

Comment: @GertB. ok, i tried using this License::where('slug', $license_slug)->first(), but still getting the same outcome, apart from using ->first(), i also tried using ->get() and got this error:- Property [license_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:

Comment: @mrhn - How please help me out

Comment: @pajay When you use `->get()` method, `$licenses` is a collection (or array). So for access to it, you need to define index: `$licenses[0]` for example, so means first element of `$licenses` collection.

Comment: @silentwasd - Let me explain, i have five licenses for each Beat and they also have same foreign key but different license (id) so when i call for example the 3rd license it will show me the first license row content instead of the 3rd

Comment: @pajay did you change the parameters for the action function yet? Share the edited code.

Comment: @pajay If your license has own id, why you can't get license directly with id, without Beat?

Comment: @silentwasd - can you please direct me on how to do that

Comment: If your url is correct, this code should work...

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection to cut your code.

```php
public function viewlicense(Beat $beat, License $license)
{
    return view('frontend.licenses.view', compact('license'));
}
```

On routes:

```php
Route::get('view-beat/{beat:slug}/{license:slug}', [FrontendController::class, 'viewlicense']);
```

The `beat:slug` and `license:slug` means that we have slug as identifier to find beat or license.

Comment: i got this error -----BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Beat::licenses()

Comment: @pajay Where you have it?

Comment: when i substitued your code with mine

Comment: Do you have code like that: `$beat->licenses()` in your view?

Comment: ive just posted my view.blade.php

Comment: @Gert B - ive solved it, now working perfectly well

Comment: @pajay How you solve it? Post your answer and mark it.

Comment: I already told them about route model binding last week. They don't seem to get it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832895